# How to test same route multiple times using chakram js?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

If I test the route once, the test run smoothly.
If I try to test the same route twice, it fails saying :

> Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure
>   "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

I've been trying to make it works for hours now. 
And didn't find anything in the docs.

```
describe('Post validation mail', function () {
            it ('Should not validate account', function () {
        return chakram.post(home + '/user/valid/toto', {email: 'toto.com'})
            .then(function (r) {
                expect(r.body.message).to.not.equal('Validation successful')
            })
    })
})

describe('Post validation mail', function () {
            it ('Should not validate account', function () {
        return chakram.post(home + '/user/valid/toto', {email: 'toto.com'})
            .then(function (r) {
                expect(r.body.message).to.not.equal('Validation successful')
            })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `--timeout 10000` in mocha.opts or `mocha -t 10000` during start tests